# How can I make an image preview show up on a react project?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, filereader

So I have this app where I want to  select an image and to upload it on mongodb an the displaying it on the frontend, in react component. An everythinh works fine exept I don't know how to dispay a preview of the image before uploading it. What I have so far is this:

The two variables for the selected image and for the preview:

```
 const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState(isAuthenticated().avatar || {});
 const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = React.useState('');
```

And the function that triggers at the inputs onChange event:

```
const fileSelectedHandler = evt => {
        evt.preventDefault();
        setSelectedFile(evt.target.files[0]);

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = (selected) => setImagePreview(selected.target.result);
        reader.readAsDataURL(evt.target.files[0]);
    };
```

And the image to show the preview. Here I made it so that if the imagePreview is not an empty string to display the preview, otherwise just the image that is already loaded from mongodb:

```
{imagePreview != ''
    ? <img src={imagePreview} alt='preview' />
    : <img src={`data:${mimeType};base64, ${thumb}`} alt={fileName} />}
```

And of course the form:

```
<form onSubmit={uploadProfileImage}>
    <input type="file" name="image" onChange={fileSelectedHandler}/>
    <label htmlFor="profile-image">Choose image</label>
    <input type="submit" value='Upload'/>
</form>
```

All this doesn't break my app and the uploading of a new file at onsubmit allways works fine but I dont know how to make the preview visible before uploading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object URL out of the file and then use it:

```
      handleFileChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange}/>
            <img src={this.state.file}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

You can also free the memory occupied by object URL in the unmount phase by:

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl)
```